# asp.net MVC3 @model in partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, controller, partial-views, keyword

In my controller I do initialization like this:

```
using mylib.product;
using mylib.factory;

product p = new product();
factory f = new factory(p);
```

How do I do the same thing using the @model keyword in a partial view?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I am trying to setup some classes, to obtain content for display. I am exploring the option of using the namespace of these classes in the view. This is more of a Separation of Concern question. What are the technologies available in MVC3 that allows you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to transfer more than one instance of different classes to View.(Am I right?) If yes, I suggest to use ViewBag for it. Something like this:

```
// Controller
=========
product p = new product(); 
factory f = new factory(p);
....
// Add some value for p and f 
ViewBag.Product = p;
ViewBag.Factory = f;
return View();

// View
=========
var p = (product) ViewBag.Product;
var f = (factory) ViewBag.Factory;
// now you have access to p and f properties, for example:
@Html.Label(p.Name)
@Html.Label(f.Address)
```

Do not forgot that ViewBag is a Dynamic container and you need to Cast it to a type when you want to use its value in View

Comment: Yeah, that is the ideal I am toying with. Is there an more elegant way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766062/is-using-viewbag-in-mvc-bad

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add namespaces/classes to you view, then it's:

```
@using mylib.product;
```

Answer (score 1):

I should parse the model to the view by

```
return View("ViewName");
```

and in the view;

```
@model Project.Namespace.Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use view models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

which will be passed to the view from the controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    product p = new product(); 
    factory f = new factory(p);   
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Name = p.Name,
        Address = f.Address
    }
}
```

and then your view will be strongly typed to this view model:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Address)
```