# How to send data Controller to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
public ActionResult Detay(int? categoryId)
{
    var categories = categoryService.CategoriesToList();
     if (categoryId == null)
     {
        var products = productService.Products().ToList();  

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     else
     {
        var products = productService
                      .CategoryProducts((int) categoryId, 50)
                      .ToList();
        var result = products.Where(a => a.CategoryId == categoryId);
        return View(result);
     }

}
```

I have Product Controller and this is my method for send products to view by category.

I want to check categoryId in my View

Like this;

```
@if(categoryId==1){//do this.}
```

But I cant reach categoryId how can I send that data and get data from view?

Comment: try ViewBag `ViewBag.category = "assign";` at controller and and in view `@if(@ViewBag.category=="1"){//do this.}`

Comment: Try to pass object of product like Product prod=products.Where(a => a.CategoryId == categoryId); return view(prod); And in view you need to accept model as product

Comment: You need to access a property of the model your returning (in your case the model is a collection so maybe `Model[0].CategoryId` or you could assign the value to a `ViewBag` property in the controller and use `ViewBag.CategoryId`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your controllers code, your View receives `IEnumerable<Product>` as model and not a `Product` itself.
Either create an new viewmodel and use it:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
   public int CategoryId {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

and in your view:

```
@model ProductsViewModel

@if(Model.CategoryId==1)..
```

or in your view use `@Model.First().CategoryId`

Answer (score 0):

View Model:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{  
   public int CategoryId{get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Detay(int? categoryId)
{
  var productVM= new ProductsViewModel();
  var products = productService
                      .CategoryProducts((int) categoryId, 50)
                      .ToList();
   productVM.Products = products.Where(a => a.CategoryId == categoryId);
   productVM.CategoryId=1 // ex. your value
   return View("Detay", productVM);
}
```

view:

```
@model ProductsViewModel
@if(Model.CategoryId==1).. // then you can use like this.
```

Note: you can do that without using viewmodel. in that case declare property to model class. assign value to that property and pass that model to the view.

Answer (score -1):

You can send the category id through ViewBag,

in Controller's Action:

```
ViewBag.CategoryId = categoryId;
```

in view:

```
@if (ViewBag.CategoryId == 1)
{

}
```

Comment: Using ViewBag in this case is not a very good idea, since it is not strongly typed. And this data clearly belongs to the model.

Comment: yes i know that it's belong to model but it is very fast and clear way to perform the required task.

Comment: Indeed, strongly typed solution is always preferred, which is also very fast and more clear. Don't use ViewBag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766062/is-using-viewbag-in-mvc-bad
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262034/mvc-viewbag-best-practice
http://completedevelopment.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/stop-using-viewbag-in-most-places.html
And there are many more...