# How to display a calculated value in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET and MVC architecture. I want to display a number in a view after doing a calculation as follows

[image: the total is here[![]]

How can I display the `totalmessage` in a view?

Comment: You view model should have a property for `Total`

Comment: It seems like you're approaching MVC from a web forms background, research how to use the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a view model to hold your data.

```
public class TotalViewModel 
{
  public int Total {get; set;}

  public string Message {get; set;}
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public ActionResult Calculate()
{
  // do your calculations...

  var model = new TotalViewModel { Message = "Total = ", Total = total };

  return this.View(model);
}
```

And the view

```
@model Path.To.Your.TotalViewModel

<p>@Model.Message @Model.Total</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ViewBag** for any data to pass view,
add these code to the Calculate method you have;

```
ViewBag.total = totalMessage;
```

than in the Calculate.cshtml view;

```
<p>@ViewBag.total</p>
```

that's all

Comment: There are very few occasions where using a `ViewBag` over a model to pass data to a view is recommended.

Comment: @RyanSearle I think Op gonna use it in a Controller, and 'ViewBag' is the most common way to pass (single step) data to the View, cheap and useful.

Comment: So? i dont get what you are opposing to. Make your calculations and put it in a ViewBag. I wanted to say with "single step", Controller -> View

Comment: Since there is a class returning 'ActionResult', I assumed it is a controller.

Comment: Saves me from explaining it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766062/is-using-viewbag-in-mvc-bad

Comment: Hmm interesting, I will research on this issue, thanks for sharing. I always think (as a newbie) ViewBag is easy and fast so it is good.