# Convert ASP Classic math statement into Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

The ASP statement looks like this:

```
adjmargin = Math.round(((mysell - mycost) / mycost)*100)
```

In the Razor View I am looping through multiple fields and I need to apply the above operation to a couple of them. So for instance I have some fields like this:

```
<td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Cost)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Cost)
</td>
<td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Sell)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Sell)
</td>
```

I'm assuming I'm going to have to assign the data from DisplayFor or HiddenFor to a variable and utilize those vars in a math function but I can't quite figure out what approach to take.

Comment: You should move that to your model or controller.

Comment: How `adjmargin` is used in the original ASP code? What's wrong with simple `@Html.DisplayFor(x => Math.round(((x.Sell - x.Cost) / x.Cost)*100))`?

Comment: That would work except that the values from the DB were stored as string and double? instead of just double. The string I can use Convert.ToDouble on but the other one complains that it can't convert double to double?.

Comment: OK, this compiles: @Html.DisplayFor(x => Math.Round(((Convert.ToDouble(x.Sell) - Convert.ToDouble(x.Cost)) / Convert.ToDouble(x.Cost)) * 100)) but I'm getting an error stating "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single parameter custom indexer expressions".

Comment: Why don't you just make a view model that does this logic for you? Then just display the properties from the view model without any logic needed in the razor page.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea, but I wouldn't know where to begin. I'm new to this.

Comment: Figured it out: @(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Model.Sell) - Convert.ToDouble(Model.Cost) / Convert.ToDouble(Model.Cost),2) * 100)

Comment: Side note: @Rafe are you using "ASP" as synonym of C#/ASP.Net or actually true [ASP classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) from 1996? Please avoid calling C# code "ASP" or "ASP.Net" if former.. (consider [edit] title at least)

Comment: Updated question to reflect that this is indeed ASP Classic.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
@(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Model.Sell) - Convert.ToDouble(Model.Cost) / Convert.ToDouble(Model.Cost),2) * 100)
```

Comment: It generally considered bad idea to put a lot (or even any) of logic into a view. Better solution would be to move calculation to controller and pass through view model - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708470/how-to-display-a-calculated-value-in-a-view

Comment: Thanks Alexei, I'll try refactoring this to something more in line with best practices.